# XSLT How to pass data to parent nodes

Tags: xslt

I am parsing .xsd files using XSLT. My problem is that I only can
write output data as I found it in the current node that I'm visiting
using .

Is there any way to send some data from a node to an ancestor node?.

A simple example of what I get and I want.

-- My current code: --

```
<xsl:template match="complexType">
  <xsl:text>struct </xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>T_</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select"current/@name"/>
  <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="sequence"/>

  <xsl:text>};</xsl:text> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sequence">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="element"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element">
  <xsl:value-of select"current/@type"/>
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select"current/@name"/>
</xsl:template>
```

-- My source file --

```
<complexType name="cp_name">
 <sequence>
  <element name="el_name" type="int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
  </element>
 </sequence>
</complexType>
```

-- My current output: --

```
struct T_cp_name
{
 int el_name;
};
```

-- Desired output --

```
<!-- // First, use some data from the inner node (element) -->

typedef int Type_in_element;

<!-- // Then, use a combination of data from both the inner and the -->
<!-- // ancestor node (complexType) -->

struct T_cp_name
{
  Type_in_element el_name;  // data from the inner node (<element>)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<xsl:template match="complexType">
        <xsl:text>typedef </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="//*/@type"/>
        <xsl:text> Type_in_</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="//*[@type]/name()"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>struct </xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>T_</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="current()/@name"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="sequence"/>
        <xsl:text>};</xsl:text> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="sequence">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="element"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="element">
            <xsl:text>Type_in_</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        <xsl:text>; &#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Although your answer resolves the exact example, I was looking
for a more generic solution, where the <sequence><element> tags
in the example could exists in any place, at any deep in the
tree.